# Unhandled exception of type "System.FormatException" Input string was not in correct format

Tags: c#

I'm currently learning C# and I'm trying to get my head around class inheritance and have written some code to display a line to the console but I'm having an issue with the error in this posts subject.

It is throwing the error in the sub class PC on the string.format line. I'm assuming it is to do with the types that I am passing in but everything I have tried so far hasn't work. Any input is greatly appreciated as I want to ensure I fully understand this before I move to the next bit of training.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ClassInheritance
{
    class Program
    {
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        PC myPC = new PC();

        myPC.casetype = "Black SuperCool";
        myPC.contract = true;
        myPC.dateadded = DateTime.Now;
        myPC.id = 1;
        myPC.type = "Small form factor";
        printEquipmentDetails(myPC);

        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    private static void printEquipmentDetails(Equipment Equipment)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Details: {0}", Equipment.DisplayEquipment());
    }
}

abstract class Equipment
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string type { get; set; }
    public bool contract { get; set; }
    public DateTime dateadded { get; set; }

    public abstract string DisplayEquipment();
}

class PC : Equipment
{
    public string casetype { get; set; }

    public override string DisplayEquipment()
    {
        return String.Format("(0} - {1} - {2} - {3} - {4}", this.id, this.type, this.contract.ToString(), this.dateadded.ToShortDateString(), this.casetype);
    }
}

class Laptop : Equipment
{
    public string batterylife { get; set; }

    public override string DisplayEquipment()
    {
        return String.Format("(0} - {1} - {2} - {3} - {4}", this.id, this.type, this.contract, this.dateadded, this.batterylife);
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace the `(` with `{` in your `return String.Format("`**(**`0} - {1} - {2} - {3} - {4}"...` lines.

So
`return String.Format("`**(**`0} - {1} - {2} - {3} - {4}"...`
would be
`return String.Format("`**{**`0} - {1} - {2} - {3} - {4}"...`

Comment: That was it! Thank you. Intellisense normally stops me making such noob mistakes.